# "Ymbirtt vs The Gilded Rose" Kata

Tags: ruby, dependency-injection

The Gilded Rose Kata is a refactoring challenge, in which some frankly disgusting code is thrown at the developer, and they're told to make a small change to it. For reference, the (truncated) requirements and the original code are given here:

> - All items have a SellIn value which denotes the number of days we have to sell the item
> - All items have a Quality value which denotes how valuable the item is
> - At the end of each day our system lowers both values for every item
> - Once the sell by date has passed, Quality degrades twice as fast
> - The Quality of an item is never negative
> - "Aged Brie" actually increases in Quality the older it gets
> - The Quality of an item is never more than 50
> - "Sulfuras", being a legendary item, never has to be sold or decreases in Quality
> - "Backstage passes", like aged brie, increases in Quality as its SellIn value approaches;
>
>   - Quality increases by 2 when there are 10 days or less and by 3 when there are 5 days or less but
>   - Quality drops to 0 after the concert
> - Feel free to make any changes to the UpdateQuality method and add any new code as long as everything still works correctly. However, do
>     not alter the Item class or Items property
> - We have recently signed a supplier of conjured items. This requires an update to our system:
>
>   - "Conjured" items degrade in Quality twice as fast as normal items

And the code to be refactored is as follows:

```
class GildedRose

  def initialize(items)
    @items = items
  end

  def update_quality()
    @items.each do |item|
      if item.name != "Aged Brie" and item.name != "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert"
        if item.quality > 0
          if item.name != "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros"
            item.quality = item.quality - 1
          end
        end
      else
        if item.quality < 50
          item.quality = item.quality + 1
          if item.name == "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert"
            if item.sell_in < 11
              if item.quality < 50
                item.quality = item.quality + 1
              end
            end
            if item.sell_in < 6
              if item.quality < 50
                item.quality = item.quality + 1
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
      if item.name != "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros"
        item.sell_in = item.sell_in - 1
      end
      if item.sell_in < 0
        if item.name != "Aged Brie"
          if item.name != "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert"
            if item.quality > 0
              if item.name != "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros"
                item.quality = item.quality - 1
              end
            end
          else
            item.quality = item.quality - item.quality
          end
        else
          if item.quality < 50
            item.quality = item.quality + 1
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class Item
  attr_accessor :name, :sell_in, :quality

  def initialize(name, sell_in, quality)
    @name = name
    @sell_in = sell_in
    @quality = quality
  end

  def to_s()
    "#{@name}, #{@sell_in}, #{@quality}"
  end
end
```

So, the first thing I did was add some specs:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'gilded_rose')
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec::Matchers.define :update_to do |sell_in, quality|
  match do |item|
    new_item = update(actual)
    expect(new_item.sell_in).to eq sell_in
    expect(new_item.quality).to eq quality
  end
  failure_message do |actual|
    new_item = update(actual)
    "Expected #{actual} to end up with sell_in=#{sell_in} and quality=#{quality}. Got #{new_item}."
  end

  def update(item)
    item.clone.tap{|i| GildedRose.new([i]).update_quality}
  end
end

describe GildedRose do
  describe "#update_quality" do
    it "does not change the name" do
      items = [Item.new("foo", 0, 0)]
      GildedRose.new(items).update_quality
      expect(items[0].name).to eq "foo"
    end

    it "decreases the quality of an in-date item by 1" do
      expect(Item.new("foo", 10, 10)).to update_to 9,9
      expect(Item.new("foo", 1, 10)).to update_to 0,9
    end

    it "decreases the quality of an out-of-date item by 2" do
      expect(Item.new("foo", 0, 10)).to update_to -1,8
    end

    it "does not drop quality below 0" do
      expect(Item.new("foo", 0, 0)).to update_to -1,0
    end

    it "does not decrease the quality or sell by of sulfuras" do
      expect(Item.new("Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros", 10, 10)).to update_to 10,10
    end

    it "increases the quality of in-date aged brie" do
      expect(Item.new("Aged Brie", 10, 10)).to update_to 9,11
    end

    it "rapidly increases the quality of out-of-date aged brie" do
      expect(Item.new("Aged Brie", 0, 10)).to update_to -1, 12
    end

    it "does not increase the quality of any item over 50" do
      items = [Item.new("Aged Brie", 10, 50), Item.new("Aged Brie", 0, 49), Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 9, 49)]
      GildedRose.new(items).update_quality
      items.each do |item|
        expect(item.quality).to eq 50
      end
    end

    it "increases the quality of a backstage pass more than 10 days before its sell by date" do
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 11, 10)).to update_to 10,11
    end

    it "rapidly increases the quality of a backstage pass between 6 and 10 days before its sell by date" do
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 10, 10)).to update_to 9,12
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 6, 10)).to update_to 5,12
    end

    it "very rapidly increases the quality of a backstage pass between 1 and 5 days before its sell by date" do
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 5, 10)).to update_to 4,13
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 1, 10)).to update_to 0,13
    end

    it "drops the quality of a backstage pass to 0 beyond its sell by date" do
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", 0, 10)).to update_to -1,0
      expect(Item.new("Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert", -3, 10)).to update_to -4,0
    end

    it "rapidly decreases the quality of a conjured item" do
      expect(Item.new("Conjured mana cake", 10, 10)).to update_to 9,8
      expect(Item.new("Conjured mana cake", 0, 10)).to update_to -1,6
    end

  end

end
```

And then the next thing I did was introduce everyone's favourite buzzword: dependency injection, refactoring the original main class into this:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'active_support/inflector'

Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'mechanics', '*')).each{|f| require f}

class GildedRose

  def initialize(items)
    @items = items
    mechanics = load_mechanics
    @items.each do |item|
      mechanics.each{|m| item.extend(m) if m.matches?(item)}
    end
  end

  def update_quality
    @items.each(&:update)
  end

  private
  def load_mechanics
    Dir.glob(File.join('mechanics', '*')).map{|mechanic_file| load_mechanic_from(mechanic_file)}.sort_by(&:priority)
  end

  def load_mechanic_from(file_name)
    constant_name = file_name.chomp(File.extname(file_name)).camelize
    begin
      constant_name.constantize
    rescue NameError
      raise LoadError, "Expected #{file_name} to define #{constant_name}"
    end
  end

end
```

Each item now has some number of mechanics glommed onto it when the `GildedRose` class is instantiated. Each mechanic then defines the minimal amount of behaviour necessary for the item to do its job.

**mechanics/base.rb:**

```
module Mechanics
  module Base
    def self.matches?(item)
      true
    end
    def self.priority
      0
    end
    private
    def age
      self.sell_in -= 1
    end
    def degrade
      self.quality -= self.sell_in < 0 ? 2 : 1
    end
    def clamp_quality
      self.quality = [self.quality, 0].max
      self.quality = [self.quality, 50].min
    end
    public
    def update
      age
      degrade
      clamp_quality
    end
  end
end
```

**mechanics/legendary.rb:**

```
module Mechanics
  module Legendary
    def self.matches?(item)
      item.name == "Sulfuras, Hand of Ragnaros"
    end
    def self.priority
      1
    end
    public
    def update
    end
  end
end
```

**mechanics/time_limited.rb:**

```
module Mechanics
  module TimeLimited
    def self.priority
      2
    end
    def self.matches?(item)
      item.name == "Backstage passes to a TAFKAL80ETC concert"
    end
    private
    def degrade
      case
      when self.sell_in < 0
        self.quality = 0
      when self.sell_in < 5
        self.quality += 3
      when self.sell_in < 10
        self.quality += 2
      else
        self.quality += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**mechanics/vintage.rb:**

```
module Mechanics
  module Vintage
    public
    def self.matches?(item)
      item.name == "Aged Brie"
    end
    def self.priority
      2
    end
    private
    def degrade
      self.quality += self.sell_in < 0 ? 2 : 1
    end
  end
end
```

At this point, it's pretty easy to make the change to allow conjured items to be implemented, by creating the file mechanics/conjured.rb with the content:

```
 module Mechanics
   module Conjured
    def self.priority
      2
    end
    def self.matches?(item)
      item.name =~ /conjured/i
    end
    private
    def degrade
      self.quality -= self.sell_in < 0 ? 4 : 2
    end
   end
 end
```

At this point, all the specs passed and I considered the challenge complete (save for a bunch of shuffling behaviour round to generally make things neater), which brings me to the review objectives:

- Is this coherent, or does it just look like the ramblings of a madman? The primary goal here is to make something that's more maintainable, and I've a little worry that by adding in all this autoloady stuff I've actually made it harder to tell what's going on.
- I've never used rspec before. Have I made any stylistic blunders? Are there any features I should have been using but didn't?
- Dependency injection is something I've read about, but never seen implemented. Is there a cleaner way of doing it here? `priority` seems a bit kludgey, but I like what it lets me do; I can start layering mechanics on top of each other to make blessed, enchanted, masterwork, etc items if I want to.

Of course, feel free to comment on anything and everything, but the above is what I'm interested in right now. The code's all been pushed to [GitHub](https://github.com/Ymbirtt/ruby-gilded-rose-kata), so if you want to comment on my commit messages feel free to do that, too.

Comment: i will try to elaborate on this later if no one else answers, but yeah, your suspicion is correct and your refactoring is over-engineered and not easy to follow.  One small and easy thing: choose clear names.  I don't see the word 'Mechanic' anywhere in the problem specs, so why is it the primary name in your solution?

Comment: Your GitHub changes would be easier to comment on if it were in the form of a pull request.